# get shortcut intent info from android applications

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut

when the user clicks a button he gets the list of apps that support shortcuts with this code.

```
Intent j;
j = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT));
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Create a Shortcut");
startActivityForResult(j, choose_app_for_shortcut);
```

after he chooses the app, I show the user the list of the shortcuts this app supports with this code in the onActivityResul() method

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        switch(requestCode){
        case: choose_app_for_shortcut
            Intent i = data.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT);
            startActivityForResult(data, pick_shortcut_from_app);
            break;
        case pick_shortcut_from_app:
             ?
             ?
    }
}
```

the question is: what code do i need in: ( `case: pick_shortcut_from_app` ) to get the info i need to run this shortcut? the end goal is to have this information stored in a file so that the app remembers the choice and it can launch the shortcut intent after the app closes. i tried a few things but it led to the app crashing so your help would be greatly appreciated!

i went one step further using this code

```
    String uri = data.toURI().toString();
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.getIntent(uri));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i get i weird message asking me what app i want to use to complete this action. and the app from which the shortcut comes is not in the list!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like here:

```
 startActivity(Intent.getIntent(uri));
```

You are actually using an intent that has not the right action set. Try this instead:

```
 Intent intent = Intent.getIntent(uri);
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
 startActivity(intent);
```